# Why my session object's updates won't show on page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following collection stored in a `session` object along with its `controller` and `action` handles it.

```java
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Remove(int id)
    {
        List<Sample> lst = (List<Sample>)Session["obj1"];

        foreach (var item in lst)
        {
            if (item.Id == id)
            {
                lst.Remove(item);
                break;
            }
        }

        return PartialView("_p1", lst);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Sample> lst;

        if (Session["obj1"] == null)
        {
            lst = new List<Sample>();

            lst.Add(new Sample { Id = 10, Name = "grant williams" }); 
            lst.Add(new Sample { Id = 11, Name = "John Howard" }); 
            lst.Add(new Sample { Id = 12, Name = "Ken walker" }); 
            lst.Add(new Sample { Id = 13, Name = "Bondi Rogers" }); 

           Session["obj1"] = lst;
        }

        return View((List<Sample>)Session["obj1"]);
    }
}
```

Here is the Index.cshtml:

```html
@model IEnumerable<test1.Models.Sample>

<div id="results">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
        </th>
            <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class="edit", value=item.Id}) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id }, new { @class="del", value=item.Id})
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
    </div>

@section Scripts{

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $('document').ready(function () {
            $('.del').on('click', function (evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                var x = $('.del').attr('value');

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("Remove", "Home")',
                    method: 'post',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ 'id': x }),
                    contentType: 'application/json chartset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#results').html(data);
                    },
                    error: function () { alert('error'); }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

    }
```

Here is the partial view _p1.cshtml:

```html
@model IEnumerable<test1.Models.Sample>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
        </th>
            <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class="edit", value=item.Id}) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id }, new { @class="del", value=item.Id})
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

When I load page at first load, all loads fine. When I click the `delete` to `delete` a records the record deletes and page shows as updated. But horrifying part is when I take a look at source view, it still shows the deleted record on source view but when I refresh the pages it goes away. 
But it was an `ajax` call so it should be refreshing the part that has records. In Addition to that, assume I have not refreshed the page, then if I click the any delete button it looks for a `view` and throws an error. [Here is video that will visually show what happens](https://youtu.be/uIouJc4hG_0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After removing the item, You need to set the updated list back to session.

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Remove(int id)
 {
    List<Sample> lst = (List<Sample>)Session["obj1"];

     foreach (var item in lst)
     {
          if (item.Id == id)
          {
              lst.Remove(item);
               break;
           }
     }
     Session["obj1"]=lst;
     return PartialView("_p1", lst);
 }
```

Also for your second problem, You registered the `click` event when the page loaded. That coded is for any current elements with `del` class. It won't work for any elements added to DOM later. You need to use jQuery [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event delegation method to add the click event code so that it will work for future elements(dynamically injected to DOM later) also.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click','.del', function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       //do your ajax code here


    });
});
```

Comment: yep : ) i forgot to add that line, but even when i add still the same problem exists!

Comment: when i add the click event like you stated, now it wont even update, it directly asks for another view

Comment: Do you have any script errors ? I renamed evt to e in my example. It should work.

Comment: Sorry i had a typo. Don't put document in single quote. Please see my update.

Comment: @Shyu actually it worked, when i refreshed the page it started to work! TX